# sending variables from java to xml in android stodio

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make Column graph, that each Column is in fact int variable from my java.
I made all the buttons and Ijust have to put somehow the variables in the buttons's layout_height.

so anyone know how to do it?

Comment: use setText() Function for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btnFirst = findViewById(R.id.btnFirst);
    //change height
    btnFirst.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(5, 5));
    //change text
    btnFirst.setText("your text");
```